# How do I replace one of the JSON object value with another value in python?

Tags: python

**JSON String**

```
message = '{ "messageId": "Sending Sensor Data",  "deviceId": "", "eventTemplateId": "",  "Latitude": 12.874,  "Longtide": 56.257,  "Registration": "",  "Battery": 100,  "Idle": 0,  "Occupied": "1" }'
```

**Random no generator**

```
occupied = random.randrange(1, 101, 2)
```

I need to replace the "Occupied": "1" into "Occupied": with occupied string.

**Solutions Tried:**

```
message = '{ "messageId": "Sending Sensor Data",  "deviceId": "", "eventTemplateId": "",  "Latitude": 12.874,  "Longtide": 56.257,  "Registration": "",  "Battery": 100,  "Idle": 0,  "Occupied": "%s" }'.format(occupied)
```

Am I missing something here? I am clueless to identify. Sorry being stupid and I am new to python lang

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: You should not work with JSON as a string. Decode the JSON into a dict, modify it, re-encode it to JSON.

Comment: It's also unclear what  exactly isn't working here.

Comment: Thanks deceze. I got you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to a JSON object and then assign the required value to it.

```
import json
import random
message = '{ "messageId": "Sending Sensor Data",  "deviceId": "", "eventTemplateId": "",  "Latitude": 12.874,  "Longtide": 56.257,  "Registration": "",  "Battery": 100,  "Idle": 0,  "Occupied": "1" }'

occupied = random.randrange(1, 101, 2) 
message = json.loads(message)
message['Occupied'] = occupied
```

Comment: And use `json.dumps(message)` to rebuild message to string :)

Comment: Thanks. It does the magic

Comment: @y_r_k. You are welcome. Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks